# Create and share a torrent from console or web in windows

Tags: java, windows, client, bittorrent, seed

Is there any torrent client for windows where I can add a torrent to seed, using console or web?

I'm developing a java application, that creates/donwloads torrents. I'm using the transdroid library for client porposes. This library does not provide create+seed operations. In linux, I'm using transmission, that can be controlled throw console, and, therefore, also from java. However, transmission-daemon does not exist in windows. UTorrent does not support create+sahre torrents from web neither from console. Azureus has the same probelm.

Any options?

Thanks